# PHP5 mysql_close

Tags: php

Is it good to use mysql_close in PHP5? Can I do like Open mysql connection, do some stuffs and at end close database connection??

Is this good approach for heavy web site? means large hit on web site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to call it explicitly. PHP does it for you at the end of each request. So basically, it makes no difference :)